# Ajax access django ManyToManyField by id

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, many-to-many

My models:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=24)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings=models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

My views:

```
def get_pizza(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        pizza_list=[]
        pizza_list=Pizza.objects.all()
        pizza_list_json = serializers.serialize('json', pizza_list)
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'OK', 'data': { 
            'pizza_list': pizza_list_json, 
        }})
```

My Javascript:

```
function get_pizza() {
    $.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/get_pizza/',
        data: {
        },
        success: function (lista) {
            if (lista.result === 'OK') {
                var pizza_list_json=lista.data.pizza_list;
                pizza_list = JSON.parse(pizza_list_json);
                make_pizza(pizza_list);
            };
        }
    });
};

function make_pizza() {
    for (i=i; i<pizza_list.length; i++) {
        var myfield=toppings;
        var list_elem=pizza_list[i].fields[myfield];
    };
};
```

The problem is that `list_elem=[1, 4]` contains the id of the objects while I need the names `list_elem=[tomato, peperoni]`. With a foreign key I can use the `to_field=name` option in the model but with a `ManyToManyField` I can't.
I tried `myfield__name` but doesn't work (it give `myfield__name is not defined`  error).
So, what can I do? I have to define the `pizza_list` in a different way in my view? Which is an efficient way to handle this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new view that takes the `id` as a parameter and returns the name in JSON, e.g. `{"name": "Jalapeno"}`.
2. Create a function that sends a request to the url connected to that view you created and captures the `name` variable from JSON response.
3. Display the value where you want, e.g. `displayElemName(elem_id)`.

The above is the general idea you can use to solve your problem. However, this will query the database as many times as there are items in your list. If you are OK with this then this will work just fine.

Comment: There isn't a more efficient way? because pizza_list is very long (thousands of element) so that means some thousands of requests

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you can do this from Python e.g. something like `get_display_name()`, but not from JavaScript, because it doesn't have access to the relation.